# How to assign URL query parameter before the last parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build an API Proxy in NodeJS it makes a request to an external 3rd party API. The API endpoint needs a parameter named "pages=(int)" appended to each request. Now this parameter must always be the last parameter in the request and the proxy code I'm using appends the "api_key" parameter as the last parameter.

So when I make a request to localhost/trending/data/day&page=1

It gets parsed like this

/trending/data/day&page=1?api_key=testkey123

How do I make it like this

/trending/data/day?api_key=testkey123&page=1

My Code

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config(); 
const config = require('./config/config');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = config.port;
app.use(cors());

app.use('/', function(req, res) {

  let url =  config.apiUrl + req.url;
  let query = config.assignKey(req.query);

  req.pipe(request({ qs: query , uri: url })).pipe(res);

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port:${port`);
});
```

config.js

```
let config = {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
    apiKeyName: process.env.API_KEY_NAME,
    apiKeyValue: process.env.API_KEY_VALUE,
    port: process.env.PORT || 4000,
    assignKey: assignKey
}

function assignKey(query){
  let obj = {};
  obj[config.apiKeyName] = config.apiKeyValue;
  return Object.assign(query, obj);
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

First it should be mentioned that you're using an object to store the query parameters. Before ES2015 the order wasn't specified. Since ES2015 the order for string keys is specified (chronological in the order they were inserted). Since this is Node.js code the older standards shouldn't be a problem.

You can swap the objects:

```
function assignKey(query){
  let obj = {};
  obj[config.apiKeyName] = config.apiKeyValue;
  return Object.assign(obj, query);
}
```

The call

```js
const query = { page: 1 };
const obj = { apiKey: 'abc' };
console.log(Object.assign(query, obj));
```

copies all properties from `obj` to `query` and returns `query`. All properties from `obj` are after `query`. If you swap the objects

```js
const query = { page: 1 };
const obj = { apiKey: 'abc' };
console.log(Object.assign(obj, query));
```

the properties from `query` are copied to `obj` and you changed the order.

Usually it's even better to create a new object

```js
const query = { page: 1 };
const obj = { apiKey: 'abc' };
console.log(Object.assign({}, obj, query));
```

Comment: I tried your code and swapped the function but it doesn't seems to be working for me some reason. final URL is same as before.

Comment: @neo81040 Have you checked the `query` object? Did it change the order?

Comment: @neo81040 Are you using a JavaScript standard before ES2015?

Comment: @jaaba I’m not sure I’m using a GitHub library https://github.com/jesperorb/node-api-proxy

Comment: @neo81040 Then you should find out because it works for me. `request({ qs: { apiKey: 123, page: 1 }, uri: 'http://www.google.com' })` creates a request for HREF `http://www.google.com/?apiKey=123&page=1` and `request({qs: { page: 1, apiKey: 123 }, uri: 'http://www.google.com' })` creates a request for HREF `http://www.google.com/?page=1&apiKey=123`